How to restart gunicorn when used with config file
I am using gunicorn to serve a django application. I am using a config file and starting gunicorn using the command
gunicorn -c config/gunicorn/dev.py

I want to know how to restart gunicorn. i am not able to use
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn

command which gives the below message:

Failed to restart gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found.

I am very sure that gunicorn is running as I am able to use the application on the web. What is the way to restart gunicorn in this case.
Below is the config file of gunicorn:
# Django WSGI application path in pattern MODULE_NAME:VARIABLE_NAME
wsgi_app = "someapp.wsgi:application"
# The granularity of Error log outputs
loglevel = "debug"
# The number of worker processes for handling requests
workers = 2
# The socket to bind
bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
# Restart workers when code changes (development only!)
reload = True
# Write access and error info to /var/log
accesslog = errorlog = "/var/log/gunicorn/dev.log"
# Redirect stdout/stderr to log file
capture_output = True
# PID file so you can easily fetch process ID
pidfile = "/var/run/gunicorn/dev.pid"
# Daemonize the Gunicorn process (detach & enter background)
daemon = True


I figured out. We need to run the command sudo killall gunicorn. and then we can restart gunicorn with command gunicorn -c gunicornconfigfile

I think you need to add gunicorn as a system service and then you'll be able to use systemctl restart gunicorn. Is this development environment?

Thanks for suggestion. Yes, its dev env for gunicorn..can u suggest how to add that?

This is a simple enough start: https://dev.to/tkirwa/create-a-systemd-service-script-for-running-gunicorn-to-serve-your-application-5aea
